# socket.io - manage server and connections

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, websocket, socket.io

i am new to java script and web apps. i am trying to create a web application.
i use socket.io 2.1.1 to create websockets.

```
var app = require('../app');
var https = require('https');


 var server = https.createServer({
 key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../host.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../host.cert')
 },
 app);


var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

i need to block or resume accepting connections based on events i receive.

```
something.on('block',()=>{
  //block all incomming connections and terminate all existing connections
  io.close();
});
something.on('resume',()=>{
// i have not code for this case
});
```

my problem is that after i close server `io.close()` i dont know how to resume it.

i tried to create a new server but it did not work and clients did not connect to server.

```
something.on('resume',()=>{
 io = require('socket.io')(server);
// not work , client do not connect
});
```

how  can i resume the server ?

**UPDATE:**

i understood that after `io.close();` , the express web server also closed.(because i use angular cli ,I was not sensed express server was closed)

i solve my problem by creating a new express and a socket.io and initialize them from first , but i am not sure this is the best solution . have any one a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not type mistake, you simply forgot to activate the socket on again:

```
something.on('resume',()=>{
  io = require('socket.io')(server); 
  io.on('connection',
    socketData => {
      console.log(`Connected again`)
    }
  )
)
```